# Given a list of strings, can I create different string?

Tags: python, string

So, I'm trying to make a function that returns True if, with given list of string, it might create a `key word` (different string).
For example, `if list = ["He", "ll", "o"]` can create word `Hello`.

So far, I got this:

```
def canCreateString(pieces, wholeString):
    temp = ""
    result = True
    for each in wholeString:
        result = False
        temp += each
        if temp in pieces:
            temp = ""
            result = True
    return result

print(canCreateString(["dis", "il", "lusio", "ned"], "disillusioned"))
```

And it works... kinda.
Now, it creates string with those pieces:
dis il lusio ned
But, what if we edit list to:

```
["dis", "il", "illusio", "ned"]
```

Now, it also should create string from pieces:
dis illusio ned

But instead, it tries like this:

```
dis il [can't match more]
```

So my code is flawed*. Do you have any idea I could rewrite code so it works better?

Comment: I suppose you meant "my code is _flawed_", otherwise you shouldn't need any help :) Do the substrings in the list need to be ordered correctly? For example should `canCreateString(["ll", "o", "He"], "Hello")` be `True` or `False`? Also, should it be case-sensitive or case-insensitive?

Comment: Ah, you're right ;) It's flawed. It's just for a learning purpose, so it doesn't matter if case-sensitive or case-insensitive (I guess, .lower() would do that).
But they do not need to be ordered correctly.

Comment: can a piece be used twice? for example, `canCreateString(['f','r','e'], 'free')` returns `True`?

Comment: Yes, they can be used twice.

Comment: I have an idea in mind, though I'm not sure it's correct - maybe creating a recursive function, where you slice the wanted string and try to match the pieces for every possible slice. I know it's not detailed enough, but perhaps you'll catch my point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is probably a recursive one: If `wholeString` starts with a piece from `pieces`, remove it from the start of `wholeString` and then call `canCreateString` on the remaining text.

```
def canCreateString(pieces, wholeString):
    if not wholeString:
        return True

    for piece in pieces:
        if wholeString.startswith(piece):
            remainder = wholeString[len(piece):]
            if canCreateString(pieces, remainder):
                return True

    return False
```

To visualize the execution flow, `canCreateString(["dis", "il", "illusio", "ned"], "disillusioned")` would be evaluated like this:

1. `canCreateString(["dis", "il", "illusio", "ned"], "disillusioned")` is called.
2. "disillusioned" starts with "dis", so it's removed from the string.

   1. `canCreateString(["dis", "il", "illusio", "ned"], "illusioned")` is called.
   2. "illusioned" starts with "il", so it's removed from the string.

      1. `canCreateString(["dis", "il", "illusio", "ned"], "lusioned")` is called.
      2. "lusioned" doesn't start with any of the pieces, so `False` is returned.
   3. "illusioned" starts with "illusio", so it's removed from the string.

      1. `canCreateString(["dis", "il", "illusio", "ned"], "ned")` is called.
      2. "ned" starts with "ned", so it's removed from the string.

         1. `canCreateString(["dis", "il", "illusio", "ned"], "")` is called.
         2. Since the input string is empty, `True` is returned.

---

An alternative solution is to use regex. You create a regex pattern of the form `(?:dis|il|illusio|ned)*` and check if it matches the string:

```
import re

def canCreateString(pieces, wholeString):
    pieces = map(re.escape, pieces)
    pattern = r'(?:{})*'.format('|'.join(pieces))
    return bool(re.fullmatch(pattern, wholeString))
```

Comment: I think the solution should be without repetition, for which you would need to modify your recursion a little. (also this has a very poor complexity for larger `pieces` arrays, DP would be the way to go then)

Comment: @DavidA The OP has confirmed that each piece may be used more than once. But yes, dynamic programming would be more efficient.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now :) Also the regex solution is clever, but feels somewhat hacky and probably doesn't teach the programming concepts behind the problem very well

Answer (score 1):

I see that I'm a little late for the party, but here is my solution (it's been checked shortly):

```
def can_create_string(pieces, str):
    if str == "":
        return True
    l = len(str)
    for i in range(1,l+1):
        temp = str[:i]
        if temp in pieces:
            return can_create_string(pieces, str[i:])
    return False
```

The main idea is this - given a string, I'll go through all possible slicings of it from the beginning (e.g, for `hello` I'll check `h`, `he`, `hel`, etc.) and look for a match in `pieces`. If I've found a match, then I need to find a match in the rest of the string (that's the recursive call). The base case is the empty string, which can be assembled given any set of pieces and thus always returns true.

If I didn't find any match, then I can't assemble this string from `pieces`.

EDIT: Oh, I see that is the exact same approach in @Aran-Fey answer. Great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 0):

Without repetition, the naive, one-liner solution would be to use `itertools.permutations`:

```
import itertools
def canCreateString(pieces, whole):
    perms = map(lambda x: ''.join(x), itertools.permutations(pieces)))
    return whole in perms
```

What this code is doing is creating every possible arrangement (different orders) of the input array, and then checking if the desired output is part one of those permutations.

But this would be inefficient for if your pieces array is larger (e.g. 20 elements). I would recommend investigating [Dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), because it's a very useful technique for a whole range of programming problems, including this one.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look into DP thing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This produces incorrect results because it assumes that each piece is used exactly once. Things like `canCreateString(['f','r','e'], 'free')` return `False` because the "e" has to be used multiple times, and `canCreateString(["dis", "il", "illusio", "ned"], "disillusioned")` returns `False` because "il" is never used.

Comment: Yes, I posted this before seeing the OP confirmed replacement in the comments, the DP is the right way to tackle a problem like this, unless one is sure that the input length will always be trivial